# Jquery text effects slide in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is the code i am working on [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z9Mfx/2/). There are three text in my code. All these texts are sliding from left to right. Right now my three text effects are there and they are animating on seperate lines but i want my second and third text on the same line. So third text instead of coming on different line it should be placed next to text 2 not on seperate line.

```
 <div id="mainContainer">
 <div id="logo">
  <img id="Img1" src="http://i.share.pho.to/cc9794da_o.png" width="50px" height="50px"/>
 </div>
    <div id="images">
        <img id="introImg" src="http://i.share.pho.to/ebe3afc7_o.png"/>
    </div>

    <div id="headlineText">
        <p id="headline1Txt" >Vintage Lace Turquoise Dress</p>
        <p id="headline2Txt" >Sale rice:$135</p>
        <p id="headline3Txt" >Reg: $150</p>
    </div>
    <div id="ctaBtn">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">SHOP NOW</button>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z9Mfx/1/)**

**IN HTML**

```
 <div id="mainContainer">

         <div id="logo">
        <img id="Img1" src="http://i.share.pho.to/cc9794da_o.png" width="50px" height="50px"/>
    </div>

         <div id="images">
        <img id="introImg" src="http://i.share.pho.to/ebe3afc7_o.png"/>
    </div>
    <div id="headlineText">
        <p id="headline1Txt" >Sports Cargo Bag</p><br />
        <p id="headline2Txt" >Sale Price $21.99     <span id="headline3Txt" >Reg: $150</span></p><br />



    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="ctaBtn" type="button">SHOP NOW</button>

 </div>
```

**IN JS**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
bannerAnimation();
});
function bannerAnimation(){
    //Jquery Animation


    $("#headline1Txt").animate({ left: "320" }, 500, function () {
        $("#headline1Txt").animate({ 'marginLeft': "-=50" }, 200);

    });


    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#headline2Txt").animate({ left: "320" }, 500, function () {
            $("#headline3Txt").animate({ left: "30" }, 500, function () {
                $("#headline3Txt").animate({ left: "10" }, 200);
            });
            $("#headline2Txt").animate({ 'marginLeft': "-=50" }, 200);
        });
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: can you check my updated code here http://jsfiddle.net/z9Mfx/2/. i need third line coming just like it is coming out but after text 2

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/z9Mfx/3/  check this and set your html like this  <p id="headline2Txt" >Sale Price $21.99 <span id="headline3Txt" >Sale Price $21.99</span></p>

Comment: actually in your code both second and third texts are coming together and then third text is going left i dont want both texts to come together. It should be like second text comes and then third text just like in my code they are not coming together.